# Queues management in C# devs team

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, queue

Here's my question, it's more about asking for your solutions and experience.

Lets say, we have several developers in one team and application which made of several independent components (services) written in C#. Communication between each service goes via queue system like RabbitMQ. How can I provide single and consistent source of all available for actual moment queues? I mean, nobody wants to scroll throw the code looking if someone already used queue for that purpose or there's no queue so it must be created. Also it would be nice to have it accessible in convenient way, like `Enum`, (probably with some description alongside, eg `///` comments?) so nobody will make any typos or something.

As a solution I stopped on some package with that enum that may be used in each service, but it requires immediate package update after each change (and those changes in developer process may happen really often, event few time a day).

Can you please advice something?

Comment: This sounds strange for me. At least you need an architecture description document. It must contain all of the services and the ways they interact with each other. One just cannot add the service and the new communication channel without changing the architecture. This question is about management, IMO, not about programming.

Comment: @Dennis well, I think you are right. I believe, that it must be first designed and confirmed, and only then packed to some kind .nuget which may be changed only after changes confirmation. Thank you :)